# why the value not plotted on graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to combine two data in 1 plot, I did it but why some data can't plotted. Below are the 2 plots that I want to combine.

[image]
[image]

I plot data from 0-100, but after I did it, only 50 data is plotted there. I can't see data -1.75 and 1.62

[image]

if we look at the data then there will be a lot of data at -1.75. but the plot that I made was unable to display data -1.75.
[image]

the code :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

x = range(100)
y1 = FC_COP[0:100,0]
y2 = FC_COP[0:100,1]
y3 = Pred_COP[0:100,0]
y4 = Pred_COP[0:100,1]

pyplot.figure(figsize=(15,6))
pyplot.plot(y1, y2, color='red', alpha=0.3)
pyplot.plot(y3, y4, color='green')
plt.title('COP Trajectory (Training Data)')
pyplot.ylabel('COPy (mm)')
pyplot.xlabel('COPx (mm)')
pyplot.legend(['Groundtruth', 'Predicted'], loc='best')
pyplot.show()
```

if I plot the data 0-50, then no data will be plotted on the graph. you can see below:
[image]

raw data :

```
y1 = [-1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259
 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259
 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259
 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259
 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259
 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259
 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259
 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75140259
 -1.75140259 -1.75140259 -1.75276447 -1.75500093 -1.75655986 -1.76060311
 -1.7647918  -1.76562956 -1.76660712 -1.76986999 -1.77553924 -1.78328446
 -1.79205966 -1.80128017 -1.81012905 -1.8166972  -1.82163198 -1.82357901
 -1.82261071 -1.82074671 -1.81822007 -1.81636453 -1.81564702 -1.81527033
 -1.81504175 -1.81443033 -1.81437094 -1.81409241 -1.81413836 -1.81447657
 -1.81416081 -1.81345914 -1.81357218 -1.81299353 -1.81270253 -1.81187179
 -1.81158094 -1.81148093 -1.81202171 -1.81271695 -1.81383562 -1.81540843
 -1.81682675 -1.81810506 -1.8179109  -1.81699747 -1.8140844  -1.80655589
 -1.79343496 -1.7791088  -1.76742963 -1.75995262]

y2 = [1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516
 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516
 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516
 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516
 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516
 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516
 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516
 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61838516
 1.61838516 1.61838516 1.61821062 1.61862755 1.62048835 1.62781933
 1.63513173 1.63517308 1.63422243 1.63712545 1.64411242 1.6525486
 1.66011417 1.66732166 1.67391278 1.67859882 1.68251646 1.68327628
 1.68010703 1.67625949 1.67350259 1.67325344 1.67511057 1.67700008
 1.67751437 1.67671652 1.67709787 1.67787659 1.67810494 1.67760331
 1.67563474 1.672483   1.66989707 1.66671241 1.66348801 1.6593183
 1.65538976 1.65188146 1.64891114 1.64601911 1.64462682 1.64477479
 1.64559737 1.64675507 1.64648738 1.64523531 1.64397586 1.64128357
 1.63363921 1.62476777 1.61943378 1.6184855 ]

y3 = [-1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033
 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033
 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033
 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033
 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033
 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033
 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033
 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7514033
 -1.7514033 -1.7514033 -1.7517058 -1.754236  -1.7561462 -1.7606703
 -1.7647104 -1.767247  -1.7664706 -1.7660439 -1.772596  -1.7797234
 -1.788537  -1.800376  -1.8101913 -1.815618  -1.8204612 -1.8214118
 -1.8201836 -1.8189402 -1.8167429 -1.8155134 -1.8149923 -1.8143381
 -1.8139825 -1.8137684 -1.8140942 -1.8145101 -1.8145539 -1.8147719
 -1.8146659 -1.8143018 -1.8135153 -1.8133776 -1.8134094 -1.8129563
 -1.8129797 -1.8128327 -1.8128843 -1.8125911 -1.8121961 -1.8130953
 -1.8139915 -1.8149062 -1.8154721 -1.8135428 -1.8097554 -1.8061129
 -1.7929881 -1.7747837 -1.7632627 -1.7578887]

y4 = [1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853
 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853
 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853
 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853
 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853
 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853
 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853 1.6183853
 1.6183853 1.6183693 1.6188416 1.6202532 1.628169  1.635454  1.6372089
 1.6326773 1.630541  1.6405324 1.649353  1.657325  1.6695863 1.6771669
 1.6816461 1.6845275 1.6818959 1.6811991 1.6793923 1.6770017 1.6752759
 1.6750987 1.6759297 1.6762359 1.6762222 1.6770585 1.6778445 1.678362
 1.679308  1.6790853 1.6774668 1.6741955 1.6716726 1.6700327 1.6657158
 1.6583272 1.6556213 1.6534431 1.6492733 1.6467282 1.6455503 1.6458433
 1.6469591 1.648562  1.6490871 1.6467181 1.6442266 1.6413519 1.6302733
 1.6217357 1.61852  ]
```

Comment: How do you expect 70-ish identical data points to show up in your graph? Shouldn't they just be a dot?

Comment: even if data points just be a dot the data shoud be show up in the graph.but now I can't show it

Comment: As @Blckknght said, they are all in the same point. Hence, no line. Try adding ```marker = 'x'``` in your plot calls, to see the points.